# How to clear the deadlock while huge set of tables are deleted using cursor in sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using the cursor to delete set of tables. The number of tables is around 400. When the count reaches 105,the execution hangs up. Please find the below script:

```
DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE TBL_Cur CURSOR
FOR (select name from sysobjects 
      where name like 'xxx');
OPEN TBL_Cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cur INTO @TblName
            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN
            IF LEN(@TblName) >0
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @strsql nvarchar(max)
            if ('Create_ts' IN (select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = @TblName))
            BEGIN
                    SET @strsql = 'Select count(*) from' + @TblName + ' where DATEDIFF(HOUR,create_ts,getdate())>1'
                    Begin try
                    BEGIN TRAN
                    EXEC sp_executesql @strsql

                    COMMIT TRAN
                    End Try

                    Begin Catch

                    End catch
             END
             END
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cur INTO @TblName
END
CLOSE TBL_Cur
DEALLOCATE TBL_Cur
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: erm, what?...............

Comment: Not only do I have no idea what you mean, your title mentions an UPDATE which I see none of, and your question body mentions a DELETE which I also see none of...

Comment: @Mitch wheatI am not clear what you are asking for?

Comment: You can make `DATEDIFF(HOUR,create_ts,getdate()) > 1`.

Comment: @wewesthemenace. I am using this 'DATEDIFF(HOUR,create_ts,getdate()) > 1' already right?

Comment: Sorry comment was not complete, I meant transform that part into a `SARGABLE WHERE` clause

Comment: @wewesthemenace . you mean like this : ' create_ts < DateAdd(HOUR,-1,GetDate())'

Comment: @wewesthemenace I tried that ,its not working

Comment: I hope you know what datediff actually does if you use it like that. The difference between 11:59 and 12:00 is 1, but 12:00 and 12:59 is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query can be sped up if instead of performing string operations you do them in one go so you would have to spend lesser time in cursor.

I presume you want all the table names with xxx + they should have a column 'create_ts'. Modified the query a bit. my solution would be like.

```
DECLARE @tbl Table(tableName nvarchar(MAX) null, stmt nvarchar(MAX) null)

INSERT INTO @tbl(tablename, stmt)
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME, 'SELECT count(*) FROM [' + T.TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE
DATEDIFF(HOUR,create_ts,getdate())>1' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND
T.TABLE_SCHEMA= C.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE T.TABLE_NAME  like 'xxx' AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Create_ts'

-- Open cursor and execute each row of @tbl
-- also instead of executing each row in separate transaction, 
-- put the loop  inside transaction and commit only once.

DECLARE @tableToBeChecked nvarchar(MAX)

IF NOT exists(SELECT object_name(P.object_id) as LockedTable FROM
 sys.dm_tran_locks AS L INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS P ON
 L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id WHERE object_name(P.object_id)
 = @tableToBeChecked) 
BEGIN
-- table is not locked and can be deleted safely. 
-- still no guarantee that by the time you arrive here the table 
-- would still be unlocked.
END
```

Comment: Your script is really crispy. But again it hangs up with same problem.

Comment: I think it locks with some table in the list.Do you have idea like how to skip the tables which is locked